# LLAMA MODEL WITHOUT USING HUGGINGFACE API

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model

Is it possible to obtain the llama model alone as open source code without using the Huggingface API so that it can be hosted on our server?

Comment: What do you mean by Hugging Face API? You don't want to use their test serving? don't want to use `transformers` for some reason? want to load from a local copy?

Comment: Using the hugchat package,it calls the model ""OpenAssistant/oasst-sft-6-llama-30b-xor" using this api "https://huggingface.co".I need this model alone to be called in my server without using any api. It can be done only by filling a request form and getting   the llama weights .I need to know how we can get these codes open source without any restrictions.

Comment: You can't get them under a different license. You need to accept the terms to obtain them legitimately.

Answer (score 0):

The license for Llama here https://huggingface.co/decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf/blob/main/LICENSE is from Meta, and doesn't require HuggingFace API.